# moving text & redrawing the Image device issues

Tags: android, android-image

What I want, the text is being moved with the finger touch over the image, on the button click it redraws the existing Image into a new one which is as text pasted on it.

it works fine for v3.1 as well as on Emulator.
but i tried to test on v2.2 device it occurs the forse Close.While it has all support for the Devices.Can you help me out of here.Its gonna be crucial in few weeks.Thanks in advance.

```
///Redrawing the image & touchin Move of the Canvas with text
public void redrawImage(String path,float sizeValue,String textValue,int colorValue) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        try {
             options.inMutable = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO: handle exception
             System.out.println("#############Error is======"+e.getMessage());
        }

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);

        proxy = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(proxy);

        //Here, we draw the background image.
        c.drawBitmap(bm, new Matrix(), null);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(colorValue); // Text Color
        paint.setStrokeWidth(30); // Text Size
        paint.setTextSize(sizeValue);

        System.out.println("Values passing=========="+someGlobalXvariable+",   "+someGlobalYvariable+",   "
                                      +sizeValue+",   "+textValue);

        //Here, we draw the text where the user last touched.
        c.drawText(textValue, someGlobalXvariable, someGlobalYvariable, paint);

        popImgae.setImageBitmap(proxy);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the errorlog from logcat?

Comment: options.inMutable = true; is supported Since: API Level 11, and you don't need to load bitmap bm as Mutable. only bitmap proxy should be mutable

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know when the force close happens, like right after the app starts, as soon as you touch before text ever draws?

**Debug on the device**
A pretty easy and fullproof technique is running the code in debug mode on the actual device.  Add a breakpoint at the beginning of your function and step over each line until it force closes.

**Possibly OOM**
If you are calling redrawImage repeatedly, like every frame during a touch, then allocating of a new bitmap may eat a lot of memory quickly and cause the crash:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);
```

Then the force close might happen after a bit.  Try changing bm to a method param or member field that is allocated and read from file once.